# How to remove Hplip icon from system tray?

Tags: 22.04, system-tray, hplip

Yesterday I installed Hplip 3.23.5 onto my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop.  I followed the instructions on the HP support site for an automatic install.

I want to remove the Hplip icon from the system tray, as I only very occasionally print, and prefer to manually launch HP Device Manager if needed.

How can I get rid of this icon?  "Quit" won't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently set up a 22.04 system for a relative that also uses Hplip.

I clicked on the icon and selected "hide while inactive". Now when the system boots, the icon shows in the system tray for a few seconds, then disappears.

If you never want to see it, you could try "always hide", but I have no experience with that.

I hope this is still relevant - her version of Hplip appears to be a bit older than yours.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Icon gone on reboot.